# trigger object events from a itemsource

Tags: c#, wpf, events, collections

I have an object with an event in it, and a static function GetAll() with returns an collection of objects.

In mine WPF page I fill the itemsource of a ListBox thought this function GetAll.

Now I would like to achieve that the WPF page handles the event of every object in this ListBox, but I don't find any good way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the collection returned by `GetAll()` using a `foreach` loop and hook up an event handler to each object in it, e.g.:

```
var collection = GetAll();
if (collection != null)
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        item.YourEvent += YourEventHandler;
    }
}
listBox.ItemsSource = collection;
```

Comment: I don't know why someone think it's not useful. It works.

Comment: I was looking for something where I don't have to loop the collection and bind the events. I have many collections that change on the fly. So I was hoping that the event came directly from the object. What I want to achieve looks so simple, but I think it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your class looks like this:

```
public class Data
{
   public static List<Data> GetAll(){.....};
   ...other property and in somewhere raise myEvent...
   public event doSomethingDelegate myEvent;
}
```

My Suggestion is try create a Routed Event instead of a normal event.Routed Event allow you to listen this event in the ListBox,or  parent of ListBox.

Comment: It looks like a good solution, but for as far that I find info it is only used on controls and not in classes. All examples I found online also gives a lot of errors.

This code is not accepted by C# inside mine class:
        public static readonly RoutedEvent ErrorChangeEvent =
            EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ErrorChange", RoutingStartegy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(this));